# Constructor overloading chooses cast operator instead of struct type

Tags: c++, casting, constructor

I've encountered a weird situation where the compiler chooses to cast a structure even though there's a perfectly good constructor that receives the structure type.
A small example:

```
struct A
{
    operator int() {return 1;}
};

struct B
{
    B(A& a) { OutputDebugStringA("A constructor\n"); }
    B(int i) { OutputDebugStringA("int constructor\n"); }
};
A test () { A a; return a;};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B b(test());
   return 0;
}
```

Explanation: **A** has a cast operator to int. **B** has **2** overloaded constructors, one that accepts **A reference**, and one that accepts **int**.
Function **test()** returns an A object.

For some reason, the compiler decides to cast the return value to an int, and use the constructor that accepts an int. `int constructor`

Can anyone explain why this happens ? I have a few theories, but I would like an answer that is based on something real (maybe a quote from the standard).

Note:
I can get the expected result (constructor that accepts the type) by changing the constructor signature to:  `B(const A& a)` or  `B(A&& a)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor takes a non-const reference to `A`, which cannot bind to a temporary. You pass it a temporary here:

```
 B b(test());
 //  ^^^^^^ temporary A
```

so the only valid constructor is the one taking an `int`. You can change this behaviour by making the relevant constructor take a `const` reference:

```
B(const A& a) { OutputDebugStringA("A constructor\n"); }
//^^^^^
```

and similarly for `B(A&& a);` in C++11.

Alternatively, keeping the original constructor signature and passing an lvalue also results in the constructor call:

```
A a;
B b(a);
```

Comment: Yeap, I thought it might have to do with the fact that it's an rvalue.

Comment: `B(A&& a)` works as well in C++11, as does `template<typename T> T& unmove( T&& t ) { return t; }` for extra evil.